# How i can check if a twitter account exist in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twitter

For the moment I use this code which is functional for instagram only, I would like to use it for twitter. I have already tried to replace the element to search for (in this case here: user) by "This account doesn't exist" or "exist" or "account". It still doesn't work....

**Code:**

```
users = ["Sardoche","ElonMusk"]
valid_accounts = []

def twitterchecker(users, valid_accounts):
    for user in users:
        r = get(url = f"https://twitter.com/{user}")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        if soup(text=lambda t: user in t.text) != []:
            valid_accounts.append(f'https://www.twitter.com/{user}')
twitterchecker(users, valid_accounts)
```

Comment: Twitter has an actual API (as does Instagram). I suggest using it rather than web-scraping profile pages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but your issue likely lies within your anonymous function:

`text=lambda t: user in t.text`

The

> This account doesn’t exist

text you are searching for exists within a `<span>` in Twitter's HTML, so you'd likely be better off targeting all `<span>` elements, and searching for your desired text there.

`soup.find_all('span')`
might get you on the right track.

It would be a lot more robust to use the Twitter API here, but it would also include a lot more boilerplate setup, getting your keys, etc. I don't see a reason you couldn't just scrape twitter with BS4 like you are attempting.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick answer, I just tested your method and improved it a bit `soup.find_all('span', class_='css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0')` the class `css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0` corresponds to the span that says, this user doesnt exist. The problem is that the response is wrong `[<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Something went wrong, but don't fret - let's give it another shot.</span>]`, whatever the class called.... I think twitter blocks.
Thanks for your help!
Have a good day

Comment: This project allows me to check the existence of a twitter account from its nickname, it allows me to train in python because my level is not at the top